# Functions.php code that only runs on localhost?

Tags: functions, localhost

I would like to run an add_action in functions.php only if the theme is being loaded from my localhost development site. How would I get this to run only on localhost?

```
function livereload(){
?>
    // mycode
 <?php
}
add_action('headway_body_close', 'livereload');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the corect answer

```
if ( $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] == '127.0.0.1' ) {
    function livereload(){
    ?>
        // mycode
     <?php
    }
    add_action('headway_body_close', 'livereload');
}
```

Comment: it doesn't mean that my answer is wrong. your answer is almost identical to my.

Comment: With Xampp SERVER_ADDR or REMOTE_ADDR returns '::1', so I check if SERVER_NAME is 'localhost' instead. (Since this is the accepted answer, I copy my comment here as well.)

Answer (score 8):

A rather safe way is marking your local environment as such in your local `wp-config.php`.

Example:

```
// wp-config.php
define( 'WPSE54453_IS_LOCAL_SERVER', TRUE );

// functions.php
defined( 'WPSE54453_IS_LOCAL_SERVER' ) 
    && WPSE54453_IS_LOCAL_SERVER 
    && add_action( 'headway_body_close', 'livereload' );
```

This is also a question of readability. You can see immediately what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it to check IP address of an user. If it equals to 127.0.0.1, then this user running the site on localhost.

```
if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' ) {
    function livereload(){
    ?>
        // mycode
     <?php
    }
    add_action('headway_body_close', 'livereload');
}
```

**UPDATE:** or as mentioned @Tommixoft you can check server IP address.

```
if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' ) {
    function livereload(){
    ?>
        // mycode
     <?php
    }
    add_action('headway_body_close', 'livereload');
}
```

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] shows client IP not server ip.

Comment: `127.0.0.2` is local too. And many other IP addresses. Oh, and don’t forget IPv6.

Comment: @toscho we are talking about development pc. have you setup ipv6 on your localhost? Or maybe you use 127.0.0.2 instead? ;)

Comment: @EugeneManuilov In fact, I use not just `127.0.0.2` but many more addresses. Not IPv6 … yet. There are also local networks (here: 192.168.56.1 and more).

Comment: @toscho what for do you use 127.0.0.2?

Comment: @EugeneManuilov [Multisite on Windows](http://www.code-styling.de/deutsch/windows-xampp-mit-subdomains-in-wordpress-multisite "Article in German") with automatically set up subdomains.

Comment: @toscho ah... but I think it is not commonly used...

Comment: @toscho so he will acordingly to it's IP will change the script IF statement, that's it. of course dev machine ip can be anything.

Comment: @Tommixoft Waste of time. Use a portable solution you can drop in and forget, not something you may have to adjust.

Comment: With Xampp SERVER_ADDR or REMOTE_ADDR returns '::1', so I check if SERVER_NAME is 'localhost' instead.